# How to open appwiz.cpl with a preconfigured search input?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, shortcuts, control-panel

As part of my job I install a suite of software, and frequently find myself uninstalling one element or another to test latest versions. Each of the programs is installed under a different name, but they all have the first few characters in common. I can filter the results of appwiz in the GUI by using the search field at the top of the page to show just my applications. Currently I have a shortcut to appwiz.cpl on the taskbar, but I was hoping to streamline my workflow further by including a filter in the search field when using this shortcut so that only our applications are shown. Is this trivial or even possible?

As an example, say that I had many Intel applications installed. I want to be able to open appwiz via a shortcut or batch command with a preconfigured search for 'Intel', so that only apps with 'Intel' show up in the window that is opened as a result of the shortcut.

Thanks in advance, If I'm not being clear please do tell me how I can clarify.

Comment: Would the one line PS command help: `( 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*','HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*','HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*','HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*') | % {Get-ItemProperty $_ -ea SilentlyContinue } | where Displayname -match "Microsoft" | select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, UninstallString | ogv`

Components filtered to those containing "Microsoft" as an example.

Comment: I believe it would be helpful for uninstalling en masse, but I rarely do this, and will have to change one or two applications at most, the problem I have is that which two, and the versions of each of these, change depending on what I am testing. So really I am after a way of viewing a filtered set of installed apps, with the possibility to uninstall the ones I choose to. I thought appwiz was the best way to do this but it oesn't have any input arguments for a filter on launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I found was to create an AutoHotKey script and make it tab over quickly to the search box and type in your query there, since it doesn't look like appwiz.cpl takes in any arguments:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

Run, appwiz.cpl

WinWaitActive, Programs and Features

Send, {Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}

Send, Your query here
```

This was tested on Windows 11.

Comment: This has achieved what I was wanting to, thank you! I thought AutoHotKey would be an answer but am not at all familiar with the syntax so wasn't sure where to start with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible.

The closest you'll get is to create a shortcut to `appwiz.cpl`  using its canonical name with `%systemroot%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.ProgramsAndFeatures`

There's no other parameter to pass in for `Microsoft.ProgramsAndFeatures`.

If you want to see what Intel applications are installed, you'd be better using `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product`